# WSO2 - Identity server 6.1.0 - Error jsp and resourceBundle errors while running the tutorial sample

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying the following tutorial for multi factor authentication: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/username-and-password

The steps were done and i opened the login page of the sample SAML tutorial web application. The first screen was displayed correctly but when i click on login, i am redirected to a WSO2 identity server page with an error. My installation is fresh. In carbon log file i can see the following error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint].[default]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/authenticationendpoint] threw exception [/login.jsp (line: [36], column: [1]) JSP file [localize.jsp] not found] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp (line: [36], column: [1]) JSP file [localize.jsp] not found
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:384)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:485)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1802)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:141)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:127)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:202)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthParameterFilter.doFilter(AuthParameterFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

After creating an empty localize.jsp and init-url.jsp under ISKM_HOME_6.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint , i got the following error:

resourceBundle cannot be resolved to a variable all over the jsp page.

Then i brought the localize.jsp and init-url from previous versions, the resource bundle error was then solved, but i got new errors as follows:

```
 An error occurred at line: [386] in the jsp file: [/basicauth.jsp]
 userTenantDomain cannot be resolved to a variable
 383:                 urlWithoutEncoding = 
 applicationDataRetrievalClient.getApplicationAccessURL(tenantDomain,
 384:                                                   
 request.getParameter("sp"));
 385:                 urlWithoutEncoding =  
 IdentityManagementEndpointUtil.replaceUserTenantHintPlaceholder(
 386:                                                                         
 urlWithoutEncoding, userTenantDomain);
 387:             } catch (ApplicationDataRetrievalClientException e) {
 388:                 //ignored and fallback to login page url
  389:             }


  An error occurred at line: [411] in the jsp file: [/basicauth.jsp]
  ERROR_WHILE_BUILDING_THE_ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_ENDPOINT_URL cannot be 
 resolved to a variable
408:                 } catch (URLBuilderException e) {
409:                     request.setAttribute(STATUS, 
 AuthenticationEndpointUtil.i18n(resourceBundle, CONFIGURATION_ERROR));
 410:                     request.setAttribute(STATUS_MSG, 
AuthenticationEndpointUtil
411:                             .i18n(resourceBundle, 
 ERROR_WHILE_BUILDING_THE_ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_ENDPOINT_URL));
 412:                     
 request.getRequestDispatcher("error.do").forward(request, response);
 413:                     return;
 414:                 }


  An error occurred at line: [443] in the jsp file: [/basicauth.jsp]
  usernameIdentifier cannot be resolved to a variable
  440:               if (isPasswordRecoveryEnabledInTenant) { %>
  441:             <a
  442:                 id="passwordRecoverLink"
  443:                 href="
```

<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(getRecoverAccountUrlWithUsername(identityMgtEndpointContext, urlEncodedURL, false, urlParameters, usernameIdentifier))%>"
444:                 data-testid="login-page-password-recovery-
button"
445:             >
446:                 <%=AuthenticationEndpointUtil.i18n(resourceBundle, "forgot.password")%>

```
 Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
```

Any help?

Comment: In IS 6.1.0 pack we have localize.jsp & init-url.jsp by default. Can you try by extracting a new pack and check?